# Consistent method for typecasting csvs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sqlalchemy

### Preface

I have a utility that reads csvs and uploads them to a database. I use pandas to convert a csv table to a dataframe then I convert the dataframe into a record and use sqlalchemy to insert each record as a row. My issue is that pandas' read_csv function does a lot of magic behind the scenes that leads to really inconsistent behaviors when I try to normalize the values for the database.

### Problem

My initial problem was that pandas.read_csv would treat Arrays as a pd.Object and convert that into a string when it became a record. sqlalchemy would handle that entry by splitting the string. This resulted in database array entries looking {"l","i", "k", "e", " ", "t","h", "i", "s"}. And also my beautiful null values were plastered with "NaN" or "nan" values everywhere.

### Attempted Solutions

First I tried manually catching and normalizing the values. This code iterates through all the table columns in my orm (which are identical to the csv columns) and conducts some manual typechecks.

```py
def parse_body(body, table: sqlalchemy.Table):
    df = pd.read_csv(body)
    df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: None if pd.isna(x) else x)
    for name in table.columns.keys():  # Convert types from string to python type
        column_type = table.columns.get(name).type.python_type  # type: ignore
        if column_type in (list, tuple, dict):
            df[name] = df[name].apply(ast.literal_eval)
            continue

        if column_type == date:
            df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").date())

            continue
        if column_type == datetime:
            df[name] = df[name].apply(
                lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            )
            continue
    return df.to_dict("records") # off to be inserted
```

This worked for a while but then I ran into a big issue.
For annoying reasons the csv contained a number that needed to be saved as a string. When read_csv encountered the number in the csv, it automatically interpreted its dtype as a numpy.float64 and when this was put through this pipeline created a table looking like this:

| my_column | another_column |
| --- | --- |
| nan |  |
| nan | value1 |
| nan | value2 |
| 17836418545.0 |  |

This value was used to reference data in an api and this float-string broke that api call.

### Back to the drawing board

Here are some attempts I made to comprehensively fix this issue:

```py
df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: None if pd.isna(x) else x)
df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: column_type(x))
```

> idea: Just manually convert values into it's python counterpart

> problem: codified "nan" or "None" in the database depending on where the Nonecheck was called, also required Arrays to be processed separately which broke the elegance.

```py
df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: None if pd.isna(x) else x)
df[name] = df[name].astype(column_type)
```

> idea: Use the native type coercion option in Pandas.

> problem: Same problems as above and Lists weren't supported by their native type converter. (pandas_dtype)

```py
datatype_map = {k: table.c[k].type.python_type for k in table.columns.keys()}
read_csv(body, dtype=datatype_map)
```

> Same issues as above. These are all kind of the same solution just with different vendors. (me, Pandas, Pandas)

### Last Resort

I ended up on this solution, which works for now:

```py
def parse_body(body, table: Table):
    df = pd.read_csv(body, dtype="object")
    for name in table.columns.keys():  # Convert types from string to python type
        column_type = table.columns.get(name).type.python_type  # type: ignore
        logger.info(f"{name} | {df[name].dtype.type} | {column_type}")
        if column_type in (list, tuple, dict):
            df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: None if pd.isna(x) else x)
            df[name] = df[name].apply(ast.literal_eval)
            continue

        if column_type == date:
            df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").date())
            df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: None if pd.isna(x) else x)

            continue
        if column_type == datetime:
            df[name] = df[name].apply(
                lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            )
            df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: None if pd.isna(x) else x)
            continue
        df[name] = df[name].astype(column_type)
        df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: None if pd.isna(x) or x in ("nan", "NaN") else x)

    logger.info(df)
    return df.to_dict("records")
```

I type cast everything to an pandas.object (Pandas most versatile datatype, from what I understand) at read_csv and then manually type coerce them afterward. My issue with this isn't that its repeating itself or that its ugly. I'm sure I can simplify this code.

It's not sustainable. The code is extremely fragile, any changes to the order of operations I have set here will cause the database polluting issues from before to reemerge. I need to put a comment before this function screaming:

```py
# DO NOT TOUCH
```

Eventually some unexpected value will be saved to csv and will break my function leading to another soul-search for a better solution. I think it's better to nip it in the bud here.

Comment: I think there's just too much here. Maybe you'll get lucky and someone will want to exhaustively analyse this but for practical purposes you need to deal with things one at a time. For instance, I see no reason why "ABC" would be treated as an array by pandas when reading a CSV - it should be a string. Also if you have a field that is an integer, you can set the dtype when you import it, so it will be ints, not floats. And so on and so on, NaN should map to Nulls pretty easily when persisting to database tables. In short - create a Reproducible Example that can be worked with.

Comment: @topsail I think you're right this is more like a blog post. I'll rewrite to be more replicable and repost it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question to show how arrays are represented in the csv file. Better yet, consider adding a [mcve] showing a small sample csv file, what the dataframe looks like when you import it (including `df.info()` output), and what your intended output (dict) should be.

Comment: From my experience, trying to create an import function that handles all possible data errors is a fool's errand. I assume there are _some_ requirements to the CSV file, so I would do a rudimentary check on column names and datatypes and then reject to import any incorrect CSV files with a clear error message "unexpected data type for column 5 (expected date, found string)" or something like that, and move the file to an error folder.